# javascript node.js set a variable from sql query to count rows in a table

Tags: javascript, sql, variables

I have a (postgres sql) table in my node.js javascript program. I simply wish to determine how many rows there are in it, and assign that value to a variable (n) that can be used as the code progresses.

EDIT EDIT EDIT - as requested I have now included more surrpunding code, and I have attempted to use the first answer provided.

```
db_connnection.query(display_query).then(result => {
        io.to(roomId).emit('room-display-update', result.rows);
        // console.log(result.rows); 
      
       const queryFunction = async (db_connnection) => {
            var n = await db_connnection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM waypoint", function(err,Result) {
                   return parseInt(Result.total);
            });
            console.log("There are", n, "inside queryfunction"); // this is never called?
            return n
        };
        
        var nn = queryFunction(db_connnection);
        console.log("There are", nn, "outside queryfunction"); // returns the follwoing
        // There are Promise {<rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined at queryFunction (/app/server.js:49:42) ...
```

I have tried a fair range of approaches, currently as above, but my obvious lack of coding knowledge or skill is showing. Everything is either an invalid type error or it returns 'undefined' or 'promise'.

How do I get the variable `n` to contain the number `2` (in this instance)?

so now the problematic code looks like this, with the current console.log errors shown for each:

```
        var count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM waypoint" 
        async function Countit(count_query) {
            const ioResult = await db_connnection.query(count_query).then(async (result) => { 
            console.log("There are", result.total, "inside function") // There are undefined inside function
            return parseInt(result.total);
            })
        console.log("There are", ioResult.total, "inside ioResult") // There are undefined inside ioResult
        };
        var nn = Countit(count_query);
        console.log("There are", nn, "outside function"); //  There are Promise { <pending> } outside function
```

Comment: This looks like a synchronous/asynchronous issue. What is shown in the console log if you put `console.log("Print", Result.total);` before `return parseInt(Result.total);`?

Comment: This code edit is significantly different from your original post, and i can only speculate to your sql package code and the missing code you didnt post. you can try something like this though::

var display_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM waypoint"

db_connnection.query(display_query).then(async (result) => {
        var ioResult = await io.to(roomId).emit('room-display-update', result.rows)
        return parseInt(ioResult.total);
        })

Comment: that's the downside of trying to present code outside of the section giving me grief. 
The display_)query and emit room-display-update function is and continues to work fine. No need to fiddle with that bit.
It is the 'SELECT COUNT(*)' code further down that cannot do a simple count of rows still. I have tried to apply the suggested answer to use async and await in a queryfunction approach, but it still always fails to get a count of rows into a variable anywhere, let alone somewhere usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database calls are asynchronous, you are attempting to log the value before the database has returned it. Convert your call to async/await or promise/resolve statement.

```
const queryFunction = async (db_connection) => {
      var n = await db_connnection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM maintable", function(err,Result) {
                return parseInt(Result.total);
        });
        console.log("Print", n);
        return n
};
```

Comment: OK, yet another weird thing for me to learn. In this example is there a way to make the variable n available outside of the const queryfunction bit? Something like:

`
const queryFunction = async (db_connection) => {
      var n = await db_connnection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM maintable", function(err,Result) {
                return parseInt(Result.total);
        });
};
        console.log("Print", n);
`

Comment: @PPrime Sure, I just updated the example to include a return statement. Just remember chain of functions must remain asynchronous. Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: noted that the code provided here does not successfully print anything to the console (no error, nothing at all). And the variable n doesn't get populated/created for use later on. So, essentially, this code didn't work :-(

Comment: @PPrime did you call the function? it has to be called with queryFunction(db_connection)

Comment: ReferenceError: n is not defined

Comment: Are you trying to call n outside the function? Thats a scoped variable. Post the code

Comment: There are Promise { <pending> } outside queryfunction
There are undefined inside queryfunction